# How to move the cam with the mouse in dota2?

Tags: dota-2

I have started playing dota 2 and I cant control camera with mouse, I have to use arows or to press scroll button on mouse.. 
I can change that and move it with mouse?

Comment: Probably play on fullscreen mode. Might be a bug where other interfaces are interfering with the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try going to:

Options -> Game -> Interface -> Set Edge Pan to on

If the solution above does not work, you can try going to borderless window mode and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the mouse to the edge of the screen, or if you have the option to on your mouse depress the scroll wheel and you can control the camera that way.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, need to change any option menu?

Comment: Should just work

Comment: @ywm DoTA2 has camera lock on by default now for newer accounts. You need to turn it on "Edge Pan" in the settings.